# Como verificar que sea un texto verdadero en un formulario HTML

Tags: html, validación

Tengo un formulario en `HTML` y tengo un campo llamado `nombre`. Existe alguna forma de poder validar que el `nombre` que se escriba sea `verdadero` y no cualquier texto.

Por ejemplo este que tiene `Facebook`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Facebook simplemente lo q hace es comparar el nombre escrito por una fuerte base de datos e indicandole si lo que escribio fue una palabra comun o una cierta secuencia de caracteres, al tratar escribir en el nombre como una ciudad, te daras cuenta que no la acepta, o si a lo mejor se escribe el nombre tipo empresa te indica que crees una pagina.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Podrias poner una posibles secuencias en una variable y verificar si el campo ingresado se encuentra. Aqui un ejemplo. (Ingresa por ejemplo `qwerty`)

```js
var secuencia="1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
function verificar(valor){
  if(secuencia.indexOf(valor)==-1){
     console.log("se envia");
     return true;
   }else{
     console.log("no se envia");
     return false;
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onSubmit="return verificar(campo.value)">
  <input type="text" id="campo">
  <input type="submit"> 
</form>
```

Comment: y en mi caso existe alguna forma de que al poner cualquier secuencia de caracteres. este me indique algún mensaje de advertencia o algo así

Comment: ahi modifique la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Como indica Smir Llorente Facebook lo que hace es compararlo con una base de datos de nombres.
Puedes bien crear una base de datos con Nombres etc... o si es algo simple busca una lista de nombres en Internet y crea un Array con dichos nombres.
En javaScript por ejemplo sería algo así:

```js
var datoIntroducido = document.getElementById('inputNombre'); //Elemento html 
var nombres = ['Pedro','Jose','Julian', 'Marta','Lucia','Jesus']; //Lo mejor serí consultar una base de datos
for (let i = 0; i < nombres.length; i++) {
    if(nombres[i] != datoIntroducido.value){
        alert('El nombre es falso') // envés de un alert muestras el mensaje de la forma que quieras
    }
    
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="inputNombre" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre">
</body>
</html>
```